# Can I convert an assembly to a Strong-Named assembly without recompiling?

Tags: .net, assemblies, strongname

I found [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302340) article:

But it looks like they want me to recompile after I have created a key pair.  Is there any way to just convert the assembly to a strong named assembly without recompiling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Signer](http://signer.codeplex.com/) tool to sign an unsigned assembly.

Comment: Awesome tool!  This solved the issue I had with referenced dlls not being strongly signed either...

Answer (score 4):

You can.

Use the [`sn.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx) and [`al.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) tools to strong name the assembly .

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx) howto.

Comment: How do i do that?  The link i posted suggests I need to recompile and specify the snk.

Comment: @Abe Miessler - added link to a howto.

Comment: Do you know what they mean when they say `code module`?  I tried specifying my base assembly but it gave me the following error: `ALINK: warning AL1020: Ignoring included assembly
        'c:\temp\MyDll.dll'

Comment: @Abe - from the page: `A module is a Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) file that does not have an assembly manifest.`

Comment: I'm broadcasting my ignorance here, but what exactly does that mean?  What is the difference between an assembly manifest and an assembly?

Comment: @Abe - the [assembly manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383.aspx) is meta data about the MSIL code. The assembly is the MSIL code itself.

Comment: Hmm, so is that the {assembly name}.xml file I see in my bin dir?

Comment: @Abe - No, it is embedded in the .dll/.exe

Comment: Then how do I get to it if I can't specify a dll to al.exe?

Comment: @Abe - sorry, I am not sure. The documentation isn't very good and It's not something I have done in a long while and memory fails me at the moment.